Is there any way to simplify obtaining normal and binormal vectors (for solving for normal and osculating planes)?
I am currently studying normal and osculating planes, which corresponds to chapter 13.3 in Stewart's Early Transc, 7th Ed Textbook. I believe I have a strong grasp of the concepts presented in the section, but the number crunch associated with the majority of the questions is so tedious that I am starting to wonder if I've missed an important problem solving skill. I was wondering if anyone could kindly shed some light into this situation.
To elaborate, for an applicable vector function, $T(t) = \frac  {r'(t)}{|r'(t)|}$,  $N(t) = \frac  {T'(t)}{|T'(t)|}$, and  $B(t)=T(t)\times N(t)$.
To solve for the normal or osculating planes, we would need the cross product of two of these vectors to obtain its normal vector, as well as a point to base the plane off of. A normal plane would need B(t) and N(t), and the osculating plane T(t) and N(t). Very straightforward.
The problem is that the vectors shown above are sequentially derived from one another: T(t) from r(t), N(t) from T(t), and B(t) from T(t) and N(t). If I stick to the vector formulae shown above, These vectors often quickly mushroom into monstrosities.
For example, if we have the vector equation $r(t) = <t^2, t, t^4>$,
$$T(t) = \frac  {r'(t)}{|r'(t)|} = \frac  {<2t,1,4t^3>}{\sqrt{4t^2+1+16t^6}} = <\frac  {2t}{\sqrt{4t^2+1+16t^6}},\frac  {1}{\sqrt{4t^2+1+16t^6}},\frac{4t^3}{\sqrt{4t^2+1+16t^6}}> $$
$$ N(t) = \frac{T'(t)}{|T(t)|} = \frac{<\frac {2A-2tA'}{A^2}, -\frac{A'}{A^2}, \frac{12t^2A-4t^3A'}{A^2}>}{\sqrt{\frac{1}{A^4}((2A-2tA')^2+(A')^2+(12t^2A-4t^3A^2)^2}}$$
where A = $\sqrt{4t^2+1+16t^6}$.
I won't even bother typing out the binomial vector, which is the cross product of T and the mess that is N.
I've tried to simply ignore the length denominator of each vector and solve for the plane equations, but that (obviously) didn't work. Technically it worked whenever the length was a constant, but failed miserably when the length was a function with respect to the parameter t.
I sincerely hope that I am missing something. Any assistance regarding this problem will be sincerely appreciated!
